# Convert varchar into date without day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Goal:
Gain datatype date with year and month

Problem:
Need to help to convert varchar value into datatype date

Unfortunatley, no day is included in the data from column. Year and month only.

I tried converting into date without using day but I failed.

Varchar(10) column data

```
data    
-------    
1997-05   
1984-12   
1988-11    
1984-10    
1984-02  
1984-01    
1984-04
```

Comment: To pass to date you need a day, a month and a year.

Comment: Of course it will fail, a date has a year, month and day. If you don't have a day, then you need to choose one before converting to a datetime datatype

Comment: What do you want to do with a date that has only a year and a month?

Comment: Could you have two new `int` columns storing Year and Month separately?

Comment: The problem is that I got the data that has year and month only. I gonna use the column for Qlikview with datatype timestamp.

Comment: A SQL Server data type called `timestamp`? I don't think that means what you think it does. Hint: it does not store date or time, much less a hypothetical date with no day. (Apologies if Qlikview is completely independent of SQL Server - not familiar with it.) If Qlikview has a date-related data type called `timestamp` I can assure you with some confidence that you will need to specify a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming returning the first day of the given month is ok, you can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, data + '-01') FROM dbo.table;
```

As others have suggested, you can't have a date without a day.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the day, you can add an arbitrary day to the data:

```
CAST(data + '-01' as date)
```